# (Matlab) How to crop multiples part in an image and store in cell without using loop/ faster way compare to loop

Tags: matlab, image-processing, cell, vectorization

As mention as above, i need to crop several section in an image and store in many cells using different bounding box, without a loop, because this will increase the speed (speed is an important factor for me).

So i had try traditional way,

```
for i = length_bounding_box    
    cropped_image{i} = imcrop(I,bounding_box{i})    
end
```

It work but took up some time, and i look through the web and found this code,

```
crop_image = cellfun(@(I) imcrop(I,bounding_box),I,'UniformOutput',false )
```

but it only work for I is a cell with several images and the bounding box used is fixed, so is there anyway to modify the code to do the opposite? which is crop different bounding box on same image instead of crop same bounding box on different images?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Actually `cellfun` is a loop in disguise and might not perform better than a regular loop. Have you pre-allocated all of your arrays/cell arrays before entering the loop?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with [@Benoit_11's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29775098/matlab-how-to-crop-multiples-part-in-an-image-and-store-in-cell-without-using#comment47680882_29775098): `cellfun` is a loop in disguise.
However, if you insist on using `cellfun`, you can still do it:

```
crop_images = cellfun(@(r) imcrop(I,r), bounding_box, 'UniformOutput',false );
```

Provided that `bounding_box` is a cell funciton with a bounding box in each of its elements, and `I` is the image.

Comment: `bounding_boxs` should be corrected to OP's definition of `bounding_box `. `cellfun`'s second parameter is a cell, not a function. Fix this and I'll +1

Comment: @krisdestruction, I changed bounding_box, but I do not understand your comment about the second argument

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, `cellfun` takes a cell type as a second parameter right? Originally you defined `bounding_boxs` as a function, which was not correct. Let me know if you want me to further clarify.

Comment: @krisdestruction the second argument is `bounding_box` which is a cell array, each element is a bounding box: a 4-vector `[x y w h]` - this is what I meant.

Comment: Ah okay, but my comment was to your original answer with the variable `bounding_boxs` which you defined as a function IIRC. Since you changed your answer, this point is moot now.

Comment: Hi, actually what i'm trying to do is perform vectorisation on :
for i = length_bounding_box    
    cropped_image{i} = imcrop(I,bounding_box{i});    
end;

i found out there is no reference on how to perfrom vectorisation on cell array, the best what i can found is involved cellfun function, so is there any way or method that i can use to perform the vectorisation?